# Ubuntu 20.04. Canon MX870 error connecting to device

Tags: 20.04, printing, canon

I have a strange issue with my network printer. It is found and can be added, MX870 driver is also present. I even see status of the printer like status of ink, queue idle, but when I want to print it tells me "error connecting to device".

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SCm5.png)

The URL is bnjp://[printerid].fritz.box:8611

How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating "GutenPrint" solved the issue for me. Also if one of the cartridges is empty there is no printing in Ubuntu, other than in Windows.